# Collection reference

Tags: java, collections, reference

```
@Test
    public void test_getAllIngredientsExcept_Parameter_Valid_List()throws DatabaseException, ServiceException, DomainException{
        System.err.println(this.validShoppingFacade.getAllIngredients());
        this.validShoppingFacade.addIngredient(validIngredient);
        Collection<Ingredient> expected = new ArrayList<Ingredient>(this.validShoppingFacade.getAllIngredients());

        this.validShoppingFacade.addIngredient(anotherValidIngredient);
        System.err.println(this.validShoppingFacade.getAllIngredients());
        Collection<Ingredient> ingredientExceptions = new ArrayList<Ingredient>(); 
        ingredientExceptions.add(anotherValidIngredient);

        System.err.println(this.validShoppingFacade.getAllIngredients());
        System.err.println((List<Ingredient>)validShoppingFacade.getAllIngredientsExcept(ingredientExceptions));
        assertEquals(expected,(List<Ingredient>)validShoppingFacade.getAllIngredientsExcept(ingredientExceptions));
    }
```

**sys.err's**

`[Ingredient{name=ingredient1, quantity=0.25Kg, id=1}, Ingredient{name=ingredient2, quantity=0.3L, id=2}]

[Ingredient{name=ingredient1, quantity=0.25Kg, id=1}, Ingredient{name=ingredient2, quantity=0.3L, id=2}, Ingredient{name=ingredient1, quantity=0.25Kg, id=3}, Ingredient{name=ingredient2, quantity=0.3L, id=4}]

[Ingredient{name=ingredient1, quantity=0.25Kg, id=1}, Ingredient{name=ingredient2, quantity=0.3L, id=2}, Ingredient{name=ingredient1, quantity=0.25Kg, id=3}, Ingredient{name=ingredient2, quantity=0.3L, id=4}]

[Ingredient{name=ingredient1, quantity=0.25Kg, id=1}, Ingredient{name=ingredient1, quantity=0.25Kg, id=3}]`

**Hello**

Sorry for the vague title but i wouldn't know how else to rephrase it.

**Question - problem**
currently i get the message:

> expected:<[Ingredient{name=ingredient1, quantity=0.25Kg, id=1}, Ingredient{name=ingredient2, quantity=0.3L, id=2}, Ingredient{name=ingredient1, quantity=0.25Kg, id=3}]> but was:<[Ingredient{name=ingredient1, quantity=0.25Kg, id=1}, Ingredient{name=ingredient1, quantity=0.25Kg, id=3}]>

So the code works but my test clause doesnt, As far as i know the bug is within `Collection<Ingredient> expected = new ArrayList<Ingredient>(this.validShoppingFacade.getAllIngredients());` Since the expected list is just a reference to the list in the Facade. If i was to run a for loop over the facde list to add them in my expected list it would work, but that seems abit wierd for a "test case".

Answer (score 1):

The problem may lie in `(List<Ingredient>)validShoppingFacade.getAllIngredientsExcept(ingredientExceptions)`

The last print statement should have printed

[Ingredient{name=ingredient1, quantity=0.25Kg, id=1}, Ingredient{name=ingredient2, quantity=0.3L, id=2}, Ingredient{name=ingredient1, quantity=0.25Kg, id=3}]

```
System.err.println((List<Ingredient>)validShoppingFacade.getAllIngredientsExcept(ingredientExceptions));
```

This is missing id=3 object. Can you post the getAllIngredientsExcept() method implementation?

Comment: The Equals in Ingrediënt class was based only on the names,so it didnt show id=3 since it has the same name. (What do i have to do now, answer coorect or delete the question since it was user fault?)

Answer (score 0):

`assertEquals` is going to call `Object.equals()` which is going to see if the two lists are the same pointer. perhaps try `assertTrue(org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(expected, (List<Ingredient>)validShoppingFacade.getAllIngredientsExcept(ingredientExceptions))`